# mysql query + performance

Tags: performance, mysql

is there a performance difference between

```
$a = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = 1 AND text = 'test'");
```

and

```
$a = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `id` = '1' AND 'text' = 'test'");
```

Comment: `'text' = 'test'` is a string to string comparison, one which will always evaluate to false; so while it's much faster, it's not equivalent to the first query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, backticks do not affect performance. They are used to escape [reserved words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/reserved-words.html), but you are free to wrap all your table and column names with backticks if you prefer.

I'm not sure if it is a typo, but your second example is not equivalent to the first one when it comes to the `'text' = 'test'` part in the `WHERE` clause. The first will try to match the `'test'` value to the `text` column, while the second one will always return false since `'text'` is not equal to `'test'`.

Answer (score 1):

Since `table` in a MySQL keyword, your first query will give an error.

Since you are enclosing `table` in back quotes in the 2nd query, it'll run fine.

If you have used `table` just as a place holder for the table name, then the answer is: No, there will not be any performance difference between the two queries. They will generate exactly same query plan.

Answer (score 0):

In a real case I can't think that there will be any perceptible difference. There are 8 more characters to parse, but that is about it. Having ID as a string means it has to have a type conversion.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a performance penalty for converting to/from an integer/string, depending on the type of column `id`.

The backticks don't make a difference.